# add automatic failover to my existing cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I need help with Automatic Fail-over in Hadoop. The requirement is to transfer the control from one node to another during the failure. I already have running cluster and want to add this to the existing cluster.

hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 4393174024192 (4.00 TB)
Present Capacity: 4101312667648 (3.73 TB)
DFS Remaining: 4100850401280 (3.73 TB)
DFS Used: 462266368 (440.85 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 20
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0

---

Live datanodes (4):

Name: 192.168.5.250:9866 (odin)
Hostname: odin
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1098293506048 (1022.87 GB)
DFS Used: 222879744 (212.55 MB)
Non DFS Used: 16838836224 (15.68 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1025325965312 (954.91 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.02%
DFS Remaining%: 93.36%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon May 20 10:44:50 IST 2019
Last Block Report: Mon May 20 09:12:14 IST 2019
Num of Blocks: 129

Name: 192.168.5.251:9866 (loki)
Hostname: loki
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1098293506048 (1022.87 GB)
DFS Used: 145424384 (138.69 MB)
Non DFS Used: 15433760768 (14.37 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1026808496128 (956.29 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
DFS Remaining%: 93.49%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon May 20 10:44:50 IST 2019
Last Block Report: Mon May 20 09:12:14 IST 2019
Num of Blocks: 106

Name: 192.168.5.252:9866 (thor)
Hostname: thor
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1098293506048 (1022.87 GB)
DFS Used: 8003584 (7.63 MB)
Non DFS Used: 16954404864 (15.79 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1025425272832 (955.00 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 93.37%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon May 20 10:44:50 IST 2019
Last Block Report: Mon May 20 10:08:38 IST 2019
Num of Blocks: 102

Name: 192.168.5.253:9866 (hela)
Hostname: hela
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1098293506048 (1022.87 GB)
DFS Used: 85958656 (81.98 MB)
Non DFS Used: 19011055616 (17.71 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1023290667008 (953.01 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
DFS Remaining%: 93.17%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon May 20 10:44:50 IST 2019
Last Block Report: Mon May 20 09:12:14 IST 2019
Num of Blocks: 109

Comment: I would search on HDFS HA.  There are a lot of ways to accomplish this (2 NNs, with NFS, with QJM, with SNN) and it also depends on what version of Hadoop you're running.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html , I found this link and https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-set-up-hadoop-cluster-with-hdfs-high-availability/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html][1] , I found this link and [https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-set-up-hadoop-cluster-with-hdfs-high-availability/][1]
Both will helps for setting this environment.
```